# Load chart with some series/legend items hidden by default

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I used Combination chart of Highchart. But My Problem is I want some X axis labels disabled when Graph initially loaded. In below attached image you can see what exactly I want.
[image]

```
You can see also in JSFiddle.
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gb8d9sn6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use visible property in your case

```
type: 'column',
name: 'Jane',
visible:false,
data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

see the modified [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gb8d9sn6/1/)